# A Tic-Tac-Toe win function

Tags: c

Hello everyone I am building a C program for tic-tac-toe and 
I have problem in finding its best move

- I first put my two 'X' and then put my opponents 'O' at its best
  position (i.e. Not giving me a chance to win).
- Then put my 'X' in blank places and check for my winning chance. If not vacate it and continue.

But I am finding difficulty in checking my winning chance.

When I put my last `X` the `check` method increments the `chance` variable by `1`.
But when I change my `X` position to count another chance the function the   pre-counted (i.e. the `chance` produced by the `X` which were put at the starting)

This is my code example:

```
char a[3][3];
int check(void)
{
   char op='X';
   int e,w,p=0;
   int      i=0,j;
   for(w=0;w<3;w++)
   {
      for(e=0;e<3;e++)
      {
         if(a[w][e]=='_')
         {
            a[w][e]=op;
            pri();
            i=0;
            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
               if(a[i][j]==op && a[i+1][j]==op && a[i+2][j]==op)
               {
                  chance++;   a[w][e]='_';  
               }
            }
            j=0;
            for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
               if(a[i][j]==op && a[i][j+1]==op && a[i][j+2]==op)
               {
                  chance++;   a[w][e]='_'; r
               }
            }
            if(a[0][0]==op && a[1][1]==op && a[2][2]==op)
            {
               chance++;   a[w][e]='_'; 
            }
            else if(a[0][2]==op && a[1][1]==op && a[2][0]==op)
            {
               chance++;   a[w][e]='_'; 
            }
           a[w][e]='_';
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `chance` is a global variable, so it keeps its value even after the function returns. You could reset its value by adding `chance = 0` to the beginning of the function.